# 1982 Yamaha Virago - Several things are wrong and i'd like to repair myself

Tags: engine, motorcycle, maintenance, clutch, clutch-plate

Several things have happened in the past couple days and I would like to know what could possibly be wrong before I take it all apart.

Engine dies after letting off the throttle while on the road.
When I try to accelerate the bike it almost feels like I tried to start in 3rd gear.  I can hear something rubbing in the engine and slight clicking from the carburetor (almost like a rattle but only when i engage the throttle)

Anything that you all could suggest could be wrong?

I think possible clutch plates or dirty carburetor but is that it?

Thanks for all your help :D

Bike is a Yamaha Virago 1982. 2 cylinders. I took out the carbs today and it seems as though one hasn't been working (one looks wet and lubricated while the other one appears dry)

Comment: Hi.  Can you give us your make/model/year of vehicle.  As well, how many cylinders?

Comment: It helps keep us from guessing things.

Comment: Yamaha Virago 1982 2 cylinder

Comment: Did this issue just start to happen suddenly or did it get worse over time?

Comment: Very suddenly. I was turning right at an intersection and tried to accelerate out of the turn when it happened

Comment: It should be very obvious if one cylinder isn't firing, but that could account for a dramatic drop in power and the feeling/noise of friction in the engine. Clean the carbs first.

Answer (score 1):

It looks evident that the carb has clogged and the engine might not be warm enough to floor the gas. engine dies as soon as you let go off the throttle, if you have the throttle on the gas flows through the main jet and if you close the throttle the fuel has to go through the some other hole( forgot the name of the jet), that might be clogged.

So my advice is to clean the card, it would do wonders on bikes, over the years no matter what the carbs would clog up due to time and foreign materials entering the carb.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like idle jet is clogged. You should pull the carbs and go through them carefully. Remove the spark plugs and inspect them, they are a great indicator as to the condition of the fuel delivery from the carbs.
Check this page out: http://www.gnttype.org/techarea/engine/plugs.html